# Label not working for checkbox when Iterator used for naming checkbox

Tags: php, css, sql

Below is the code which I am using. Could someone let me know why it is not working with the label name.

```
<div class="modal-body">

    <?php
        $batsmen=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
            $i = 1;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($batsmen)) {       
            echo"<div class='checkbox checkbox-primary'  style='margin-left:20px;'>";
            echo "<input  type = 'checkbox' id='checkbox'".$i. " unchecked/>";
            echo "<label for='checkbox".$i."'>" . $row['p_name'] . "</label>";
            echo "</div>";
            $i++;
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a typo on the <input /> line? name='checkbox'".$i. doesn't match the same concatenation you're doing for <label>...</label>.

Comment: thanks Eric, I did close out id name before I included the iterator. I hope you were pointing out that.

Comment: What I was saying was that the echo "<input id='checkbox' ".$1. looks like your HTML would render as <input id='checkbox' 5 unchecked /> versus you label which renders <label  for='checkbox5'>...</label> but I'm not a php person so maybe I misunderstand.

Comment: yeah Eric you were right, that was the mistake :/

Comment: If I post that as the answer, would you mark it as the correct?

Answer (score 0):

A label is given for an id not for name see the code below:

```html
<input  type = 'checkbox' id="x1" unchecked/>
<label for="x1">SAMPLE TEXT</label>
```

Change your code to:

```
echo "<input  type = 'checkbox' id='element-".$i."' name='checkbox'".$i." unchecked/>";
echo "<label for='element-".$i."'>" . $row['p_name'] . "</label>";
```

Comment: I did use id instead of name, but its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ID attribute not name :

```
<div class="modal-body">

<?php
    $batsmen=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
        $i = 1;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($batsmen)) {       
        echo"<div class='checkbox checkbox-primary'  style='margin-left:20px;'>";
        echo "<input  type = 'checkbox' id='checkbox".$i. "' unchecked/>";
        echo "<label for='checkbox".$i."'>" . $row['p_name'] . "</label>";
        echo "</div>";
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I did use id too instead of name but it still does not work. Did the above case work at your end?

Comment: Edited : id='checkbox' ".$i. " must be  : id='checkbox".$i. "'

Answer (score 0):

In your code, checkbox ID attribute is losed before $i variable :

```
  echo "<input  type = 'checkbox' id='checkbox'".$i. " unchecked/>";
```

This line give that :

```
 <input  type = 'checkbox' id='checkbox'1 unchecked/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked in the comments on the question and it looks like it resolved the issue. It looks like there's just a minor typo in the input HTML line.

`<input  type = 'checkbox' id='checkbox'".$i. " unchecked/>`

Should be:

`<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox".$i."' unchecked/>`

That would match the label HTML:

`<label for='checkbox".$i."'>" . $row['p_name'] . "</label>`